# On Properly Discontinuous action on metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, group-actions

Let $G$ acts on space $X$, We say the action of $G$ on $X$ is proper discontinuous, if for every $x\in X$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $gU\cap U=\phi$ for all $g\in G, g\neq e$

We say the action is $\textit{covering space action}$ if $G$ acts by homeomorphism and action is proper discontinuous.

Now Let $M$ be a metric space, Let $G$ be a group which acts on $M$ by isometry.

SO my question is the following, What extra conditions are required to conclude that this action is a covering space action.

$\textbf{My attempt}:$

Since, Isometry is a homeomorphism, we conclude that $G$ acts on $M$ by homeomorphism. We only need to make sure that the action is proper discontinuous.

Now, If we add a extra condition, that action is fixed point free, ($g.x=x \implies g=e$), then I guess we can conclude that action is covering space action.

**Proof:** Assume that action is not p.d.c., Let $y\in M$, and $U=B(y,\frac{1}{n})$ be an open set containing $y$. Since the action is not p.d.c there exist $x\in gU\cap U$.

$d(x,y)<\frac{1}{n}$, also $x\in gU$, so $x=g.z$ for some $z\in U$.

$d(z,y)<\frac{1}{n}$,

$d(g.z,z)\leq d(g.z,y)+d(z,y)=\frac{2}{n}$. We can choose $n$ large enough. 
Hence we arrive at a contradiction as $z$ is a fixed point.

Do I need to put another condition, that orbits need to be discrete. What If I don't assume it. Is there a counterexample where action of $G$ on $M$ is by homeomorphism and action is fixed point free, but still it is not a covering space action.

Comment: Your choice of $y$ in the beginning is sloppy.  Also, I think you might want the metric space to be complete, although that is just a guess.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Actually I have used the definition of proper discontinuous action. So I picked a $y$ in $M$. Since the action is assumed to be not p.d.c action, $gU\cap U$ is non empty, So I can choose a $x$  belonging to the intersection. Is it clear ?

Comment: When you change the radius if the balls, the point $x$ may change, and therefore so can $z$. You rather have a sequence $z_n$ which is cauchy because it is contained in the descending sequence of balls. Therefore, you at least need the space to be complete to be able to take the limit of the sequence which will then give you a fixed point of the action.

Comment: @Sak yeah!, you are right.

Comment: Think about the action of ${\mathbb R}$ on itself by translations.